# How to suppress Objective-C warning "incomplete implementation of class 'SomeClass'"?

Tags: objective-c, dynamic, implementation, warnings, clang

I have a class which is routing many messages into inner component instance. So the class have only method definition, but no implementation. How can I suppress these warnings for those dynamic methods?

**Update**

My code sample:

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject
{
}
- (void)mssageA:(id)value1 additionalOption:(id)value2;
- (void)mssageB:(id)value1 additionalOption:(id)value2;
- (void)mssageC:(id)value1 additionalOption:(id)value2;
@end
@implementation SomeClass
- (id)forwardingTargetForSelector:(SEL)aSelector
{
    if(aSelector==@selector(mssageA:additionalOption:))     return  innerComponentInstance;
    if(aSelector==@selector(mssageB:additionalOption:))     return  innerComponentInstance;
    if(aSelector==@selector(mssageC:additionalOption:))     return  innerComponentInstance;

    return  [super forwardingTargetForSelector:aSelector];
}
@end
```

Comment: You might want to consider using a protocol instead of a class here. But still, a good question (because I think this is how internal implementations of for example NSNumber work...)

Comment: If you don't want to create a formal protocol, just use a category to define the methods. When you do that, the compiler doesn't complain about whether or not they're implemented (called an informal protocol).

Comment: Thanks for reply but I can't figure out how to use protocol in this case. Maybe my question unclear. I modified my question. Or can I get a sample to applying protocol for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a protocol implementation could look like this

```
@protocol SomeProtocol 

@optional
- (void)mssageA:(id)value1 additionalOption:(id)value2;
- (void)mssageB:(id)value1 additionalOption:(id)value2;
- (void)mssageC:(id)value1 additionalOption:(id)value2;
@end

@interface SomeClass : NSObject <SomeProtocol>
{
}

@implementation SomeClass
- (id)forwardingTargetForSelector:(SEL)aSelector
{
    if(aSelector==@selector(mssageA:additionalOption:))     return  innerComponentInstance;
    if(aSelector==@selector(mssageB:additionalOption:))     return  innerComponentInstance;
    if(aSelector==@selector(mssageC:additionalOption:))     return  innerComponentInstance;

    return  [super forwardingTargetForSelector:aSelector];
}
@end
```

Comment: You need an @end at the end of the protocol, I think, but otherwise looks good.

Comment: @optional looks contain a meaning of the implementations should be checked before using it with `respondsToSelector:`. Do I have wrong understanding about @optional keyword?

Comment: oh of course i just forgot the @end, lazy me. 
It'll be better to check respondsToSelector. You can do it - so i think - without but risk a crash